# active tab is dynamically changed but click anywhere on the page change to first tab as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following tabs on my view

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-18">
        <li class="active">
            <a aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1">
            <i class="green ace-icon fa fa-home bigger-120"></i>
            Tab 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="orange ace-icon fa fa-clock-o bigger-120"></i>
                Tab2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="tab-content no-border padding-24">
    <div id="Tab1" class="tab-pane active">
         ...
    </div>
    <div id="Tab2" class="tab-pane">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I dynamically change active tab, from Tab1 to Tab2.

I've tried this:

```
  $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');    
  $('#Tab2').on('click', function() {
      $('.nav-tabs li:first-child a').tab('show');
  });
```

Which works fine, it change active tab **but first click anywhere on the page change tab to first tab again.**
how to fix this

Comment: Can you post a live example like http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: what do you mean by:but first click anywhere on the page change tab to first tab again. how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions is not clear but try this.

Based on whatever condition you have to go to the nth tab:

```
if(yourCondition)
      $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(n) a').trigger('click');
```